# Comparing item stats in APB

Tags: apb-reloaded

The compare system in APB seems a little broken to me. As far as I can see you can only compare items that you have purchased, in the inventory screens.

Is there a way to compare your currently equipped weapons, vehicles etc in the contacts buy / sell screen?

Comment: All Points Bulletin ? If yes should be retaged IMO not everyone is familiar with any game abbreviation.

Comment: Agreed, I've retagged it.

Comment: @MarmouCorp then again, if you don't know the game it might be difficult to answer questions on it.

Comment: This question lost its game tag. Readded.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to remember the tooltips when you hovered over the items to provide a lot of information, including comparisons to your current equipment, even outside of the compare screen. But sadly the game appears down (for good :/) and I'm unable to double-check my recollection against fact.

Comment: The game has indeed been shut down forever. The shortest living MMO in history.